# Does anybody know software that limits amount of keywords?

Tags: software, metadata, keywords

Does anybody know software that limits the amount of keywords in each photo, e.g. by discarding all keywords above keyword no. 50, for example? (Of course using the given sorting of keywords)
If possible with batch processing, and counting the actual words (not tags).

Thanks.

Edit: I could use xmp files if necessary, but I usually embed the keywords into the jpg.
The actual problem is as follows:
I tag images with a lot of keywords to sell them on stock agency sites. The problem is that on some sites it is better to have some extra keywords, on others it isn't.
Hence I took the habit of capitalizing the important keywords, and keeping unimportant ones lower-case. Lightroom then first lists upper-case, and later lower-case. I guess indeed having a way of stripping all the lower-case ones would be optimal...

Any ideas?

I'm not really good at scripting, so that's not much of an option.

Comment: It was possible to add such capability into Daminion, but can you please explain why do you need it?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. Small edit/update above. Sorry for the delay.